# When change focus between UITextfields has secureTextEntry is true, shift button is flickering

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm trying to rebuild my old objective-c protject to swift project.
I found, when focus has changed between UITextField not secured and UITextField has secured, shift button is flickering. Not just flickering but also works. So Keyboard has changed Upper case and Lower case again very fast. It makes user feel like app has error.

I tried same thing in the new sample project. It shows especially in Korean keyboard. And Sometime it also shows in English Keyboard.

```swift
let tf1: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tf.placeholder = "tf1"
        return tf
    }()

    let tf2: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tf.placeholder = "tf2"
        tf.isSecureTextEntry = true
        return tf
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(tf1)
        view.addSubview(tf2)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tf1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            tf1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            tf1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8),
            tf1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            tf2.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            tf2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tf1.bottomAnchor),
            tf2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tf1.widthAnchor),
            tf2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tf1.heightAnchor)

            ])

    }
```

This is the original situation in my App.(I made the image a little slowly because gif can't show the status.)

[image]

And this is sample app.
[image]

I can't find the way to fix it.
Could you give me some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an issue it is only occurs when your `textField` language not supported **capitalised locale**.

- So when you swap from `textField2` to `textFiled1` it locks **locale capitalisation** which you can maintain by using `shift` key

Comment: But it happens also in English keyboard.